# How to store previous state of checkboxes in multiple accordions

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have multiple accordions on page and each accordion has multiple checkboxes in it.
Now I want to store the previous state of the checkbox so that I can verify its state is really changed or not.
Problem is I cant use event document.Ready because in this event it shows that not all checkboxes loaded on page
because those are under accordions and they will be loaded only when the accodion expands and only one accordion is expandable in application.
So in which event I have to store the previous state of all checkboxes?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your multiple checkboxes has his own unique `id` or `value`

You want to store the `state` with respect to the `id` or `value`

You can use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to get the checked box.

```
var store;
var storeChecked = function() { 

store = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function () {
    return [this.id,this.checked];
             }).get(); 
};
```

See demo here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/29pKk/4/)